# How to find the PDF of $Z = x + UV$

Tags: calculus, probability-distributions, random-variables

Let $(X, Y)$ be a bivariate random vector whose joint density is given by
\begin{align*}
f_{X, Y}(x, y) = c e^{-|x|-2|y-x|}, ~(x, y) \in \mathbb{R}^2.
\end{align*}
where $c > 0$ is a constant. Here $|\cdot|$ denotes the absolute value.
(a) Find the value of the constant $c$.
(b) Find the conditional density of $Y$ given $X$.
(c) (4 points) Fix a constant $x \in R$. Let $U$ be an exponential random variable with rate $2$.
$~~~~~$ Also let $V$ be an random variable satisfying $P(V = 1) = P(V = -1) = \frac{1}{2}$.
$~~~~~$ Suppose $U$ and $V$ are independent, and define $Z = x + UV$.
$~~~~~$ Show that the distribution of $Z$ is the one in (b), i.e., the conditional distribution of $Y$ given $X = x$.
$~~~~~$ $\textit{Hint}$. Derive the cumulative distribution function of $Z$ and then differentiate
$~~~~~$ to see that the probability density function is the one in (b).
$~~~~~$ Note that $Z > x$ only if $V = 1$, and $Z < x$ only if $V = -1$.

$\mathbf{My~Attempts:}$
$\mathbf{(a)}$ Since, we know notice that $(x, y) \in \mathbb{R}^2$.
Then, this means that we have $-\infty < x < \infty$ and $-\infty < y < \infty$.
Then, taking $x$-slices, the integral is:
\begin{align*}
\int\int_R f_{X, Y}(x, y) dx dy &= \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} c e^{-|x|-2|y-x|} dx dy \\
&= c \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \bigg(\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} e^{-|x|-2|y-x|} dy \bigg) dx = 1 ~~~~~[*]
\end{align*}
Since, notice that $|y-x| = \begin{cases} y-x &, \text{ if $y - x \geq 0$ i.e. $y \geq x$} \\ x-y &, \text{ if $y - x < 0$ i.e. $y < x$} \end{cases}$
Also, notice that $|x| = \begin{cases} x &, \text{ if $x \geq 0$} \\ -x &, \text{ if $x < 0$} \end{cases}$
So, we need to find $c$ in four cases.
$\mathbf{Case~1:}$ If $y \geq x$ and $x \geq 0$.
Then, $y \geq x$ $\implies$ $|y-x| = y - x$ and $-\infty < x \leq y < \infty$. Also, $x \geq 0$ $\implies$ $|x| = x$ and $0 \leq x < \infty$.
So, continues from $[*]$, we have that
\begin{align*}
\int\int_R f_{X, Y}(x, y) dx dy &= c \int_{0}^{\infty} \bigg(\int_{x}^{\infty} e^{-x-2(y-x)} dy \bigg) dx \\
&= c \int_{0}^{\infty} \bigg(e^{-x+2x} \bigg[ 0 - \bigg( -\frac{1}{2} e^{-2x} \bigg) \bigg] \bigg) dx  ~~~~~\text{# since, notice that $-\frac{1}{2} e^{-2y} \rightarrow 0$ as $y \rightarrow \infty$} \\
&= c \int_{0}^{\infty} \bigg(\frac{1}{2} e^{-x} \bigg) dx \\ 
&= c \bigg[ -\frac{1}{2} e^{-x} \bigg]_{0}^{\infty} = c \bigg[ 0 -(-\frac{1}{2} e^{0}) \bigg] ~~~~~\text{# since, notice that $-\frac{1}{2} e^{-x} \rightarrow 0$ as $x \rightarrow \infty$} \\
&= \frac{c}{2}
\end{align*}
$\mathbf{Case~2:}$ If $y \geq x$ and $x < 0$.
Then, $y \geq x$ $\implies$ $|y-x| = y - x$ and $-\infty < x \leq y < \infty$. Also, $x < 0$ $\implies$ $|x| = -x$ and $-\infty < x < 0$.
So, continues from $[*]$, similar with $\mathbf{Case~1}$ we have that
\begin{align*}
\int\int_R f_{X, Y}(x, y) dx dy &= c \int_{-\infty}^{0} \bigg(\int_{x}^{\infty} e^{-(-x)-2(y-x)} dy \bigg) dx \\
&= c \int_{-\infty}^{0} \bigg(e^{x+2x} \bigg[ 0 - \bigg(-\frac{1}{2} e^{-2x}\bigg) \bigg] \bigg) dx  ~~~~~\text{# since, notice that $-\frac{1}{2} e^{-2y} \rightarrow 0$ as $y \rightarrow \infty$} \\
&= c \int_{-\infty}^{0} \bigg(\frac{1}{2} e^{x} \bigg) dx \\
&= c \bigg[ \frac{1}{2} e^{x} \bigg]_{-\infty}^{0} = c \bigg[\frac{1}{2} e^{0} - 0 \bigg] ~~~~~\text{# since, notice that $\frac{1}{2} e^{x} \rightarrow 0$ as $x \rightarrow -\infty$} \\
&= \frac{c}{2}
\end{align*}
$\mathbf{Case~3:}$ If $y < x$ and $x \geq 0$.
Then, $y < x$ $\implies$ $|y-x| = x - y$ and $-\infty < y < x < \infty$. Also, $x \geq 0$ $\implies$ $|x| = x$ and $0 \leq x < \infty$.
Which is similar with previous cases and we have $\frac{c}{2} = 1 \implies c = 2$ if $y < x$ and $x \geq 0$.
$\mathbf{Case~4:}$ If $y < x$ and $x < 0$.
Then, $y < x$ $\implies$ $|y-x| = x - y$ and $-\infty < y < x < \infty$. Also, $x < 0$ $\implies$ $|x| = -x$ and $-\infty < x < 0$.
Which is similar with previous cases and we have $\frac{c}{2} = 1 \implies c = 2$ if $y < x$ and $x < 0$.
So, in conclude that $c = 2$ and $f_{X, Y}(x, y) = 2 e^{-|x|-2|y-x|}, ~(x, y) \in \mathbb{R}^2$.

$\mathbf{(b)}$ Since, the conditional PDF of $Y$ given $X$ is $f_{Y|X}(y|x) = \frac{f_{X Y}(x, y)}{f_X(x)}$.
Also, from part (a), we know that $f_{X, Y}(x, y) = 2 e^{-|x|-2|y-x|}, ~(x, y) \in \mathbb{R}^2$.
So, we only need to find the marginal PDF of $X$ which is $f_X(x) = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f_{X, Y}(x, y) dy$.
Since, notice that $|y-x| = \begin{cases} y-x &, \text{ if $y - x \geq 0$ i.e. $y \geq x$} \\ x-y &, \text{ if $y - x < 0$ i.e. $y < x$} \end{cases}$
So, we have two cases for finding the marginal PDF of $X$.
$\mathbf{Case~1:}$ If $y \geq x$.
Then, we have that $|y-x| = y - x$ and $-\infty < x \leq y < \infty$. Also, we know $x$ is given.
\begin{align*}
\text{So, we have that } f_X(x) &= 2e^{-|x|} \int_{x}^{\infty} e^{-2(y-x)} dy \hspace{150mm} \\
&= 2e^{-|x| + 2x} \bigg[ -\frac{1}{2} e^{-2y} \bigg]_{y = x}^{\infty} \\
&= 2e^{-|x| + 2x} \bigg[ 0 - \bigg(-\frac{1}{2} e^{-2x}\bigg) \bigg] ~~~~~\text{# since, $-\frac{1}{2} e^{-2y} \rightarrow 0$ as $y \rightarrow \infty$} \\
&= e^{-|x|}
\end{align*}
$\mathbf{Case~2:}$ If $y < x$.
Then, $y < x$ $\implies$ $|y-x| = x - y$ and $-\infty < y < x < \infty$. Also, we know $x$ is given.
\begin{align*}
\text{So, we have that } f_X(x) &= 2e^{-|x|} \int_{-\infty}^{x} e^{-2(x-y)} dy \hspace{150mm} \\
&= 2e^{-|x| - 2x} \bigg[ \frac{1}{2} e^{2y} \bigg]_{-\infty}^{y = x} \\
&= 2e^{-|x| - 2x} \bigg[ \frac{1}{2} e^{2x} - 0 \bigg] ~~~~~\text{# since, $\frac{1}{2} e^{2y} \rightarrow 0$ as $y \rightarrow -\infty$} \\
&= e^{-|x|}
\end{align*}
Since, we find that $f_X(x) = e^{-|x|}$ for both $y \geq x$ and $y < x$.
So, we can conclude that $f_X(x) = e^{-|x|}$, for all $(x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^2$.
Therefore, the conditional PDF of $Y$ given $X$ is
\begin{align*}
f_{Y|X}(y|x) = \frac{f_{X Y}(x, y)}{f_X(x)} = 2 e^{-2|y-x|} = \begin{cases} 2 e^{-2(y-x)} &, \text{ if $y \geq x$} \\ 2 e^{-2(x-y)} &, \text{ if $y < x$} \end{cases}
\end{align*}

$\mathbf{(c)}$ Since, we know that $U$ is an exponential random variable with rate $2$.
Then, we have that $U \sim Exponential(\lambda = 2)$.
So, the PDF of $U$ is $f_U(u) = \begin{cases} 2 e^{-2u} &, \text{ if $u \geq 0$} \\ 0 &, \text{ if $u < 0$} \end{cases}$.
Since, x is a constant in $\mathbb{R}$. Then, we are given that $X = x$.
\begin{align*}
\text{Then, the CDF of $Z$ which is } F_Z(z) = P(Z \leq z) = P(x + UV \leq z) = \begin{cases} P(x + U \leq z) &, \text{ if $V = 1$, i.e. $Z > x$} \\ P(x - U \leq z) &, \text{ if $V = -1$, i.e. $Z < x$} \end{cases} 
\end{align*}

$\mathbf{Where~I~am~getting~stuck~on~how~to~differentiate~F_Z(z)~and~get~f_Z(z) = f_{U|X}(u|x) = 2 e^{-2|u-x|} = \begin{cases} 2 e^{-2(u-x)} &, \text{ if $u \geq x$} \\ 2 e^{-2(x-u)} &, \text{ if $u < x$} \end{cases} !!}$

$\mathbf{Also:}$
$\mathbf{Is~that~my~attempt~of~part~(a)~and~(b)~all~correct~?}$
$\mathbf{And~are~there~anything~I~can~improve~or~add~for~(a)~and~(b)?}$

Comment: It would be better  if you would focus on one question in one post.